# Parse xml with yearly changing XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Sorry for the cryptic title.
I'm rewriting a .NET Framework C# application to .NET Core and the main purpose of the application is the read XML-files we get from a 3rd party and save it in our database. A basic ETL process.

Every year a new XSD is published by this 3rd party with several, mostly minor, changes. The application needs to handle XML files from each year.
What is the best way to parse this XML? Because the structure can vary we have created the classes manually and are parsing the XML node for node and check if the node exists before we parse it.
Every year we do a diff of the new XSD and add the new properties and make the properties that are no longer needed nullable. And of course, we need to adjust the node parsing.

Because I'm now going to rewrite everything for .NET Core I wonder if this approach is the best one.
Perhaps someone can suggest something else?

Answer (score 0):

Data-binding (mapping XML structures to classes in an object-oriented programming language) is a great technique when the schema is small, simple, and stable. When the schema gets big, complex, or changeable, it becomes an absolute pain, as you are discovering. At this point you're much better off using a generic model such as DOM, or an XML-oriented programming language such as XSLT or XQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I was afraid a simple solution wouldn't work ;)
I will start by generating the classes using the latest XSD and add the properties from the other XSDs manually. And I will stay with parsing the XML node by node.